# Extracting a substring from a given string pattern

Tags: java, regex

Here are the Strings:

Example 1 - `Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_actor=Edward Norton;new_actor=Mark Ruffalo`

Example 2 - `Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_movie_release_date=12 December 2008;new_movie_release_date=20 June 2012`

How can I extract values like old_actor, new actor from example 1 and new_movie_release_date and old_movie_release_date from example 2.

I'm new to regex trying to see how can this be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it, e.g. you could use expressions that look for `new_actor=(value)` etc. or you could use an expression that looks for the pattern `(property)=(value)` (the `(...)` means a capturing group that you would then need to extract from the match and process further). It also depends on whether the format of those strings will always be the same, i.e. `property=value;property=value;...` and whether values could contain `=` or `;`.

Comment: Note that if the format is as you described above it might be easier to split on `";"` to get individual entries and then split each entry on `"="` to get name and value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using `java regex` as follows

```
String str1 = "Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_actor=Edward Norton;new_actor=Mark Ruffalo";
String str2 = "Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_movie_release_date=12 December 2008;new_movie_release_date=20 June 2012";

String pattern1="Movie=(.*?);old_actor=(.*?);new_actor=(.*?)$";
String pattern2="Movie=(.*?);old_movie_release_date=(.*?);new_movie_release_date=(.*?)$";

Matcher m1 =  Pattern.compile(pattern1).matcher(str1);
if (m1.find()) {    
    System.out.println("old_actor: " + m1.group(2));
    System.out.println("new_actor: " + m1.group(3));
}  

Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2).matcher(str2);
if (m2.find()) {    
    System.out.println("old_movie_release_date: " + m2.group(2));
    System.out.println("new_movie_release_date: " + m2.group(3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.split(String regex)`.
First, you use `String.split(";")`, which will give you an array `String[] values` with contents looking like `Movie=moviename`, then you use `String.split("=")` on each string in the first array

```
for(String str : values) {
String[] keyValue = str.split("=");
}
```

to create subarrays of length 2 with key at position 0 and value at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just an enhancement to @DerLebkuchenmann's solution

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_actor=Edward Norton;new_actor=Mark Ruffalo";
    String str2 = "Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_movie_release_date=12 December 2008;new_movie_release_date=20 June 2012";

    Map<String, String> props1 = getProps(str1);
    Map<String, String> props2 = getProps(str2);

    System.out.println(String.format("Old Actor: %s", props1.get("old_actor")));
    System.out.println(String.format("Old Movie Release Date: %s", props2.get("old_movie_release_date")));
    System.out.println(String.format("New Movie Release Date: %s", props2.get("new_movie_release_date")));
  }

  private static Map<String, String> getProps(String str1) {
    return Arrays.stream(str1.split(";"))
        .map(pair -> pair.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(crumbs -> crumbs[0], crumbs -> crumbs[1]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `StringTokenizer` and assembling a `HashMap` for result:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK;old_actor=Edward Norton;new_actor=Mark Ruffalo",";=");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String s = st.nextToken();
            if (st.hasMoreTokens()) { // ensure well-formed
                m.put(s,st.nextToken());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{Movie=HULK/Incredible HULK, old_actor=Edward Norton, new_actor=Mark Ruffalo}
```